# VPN Duration in Multi-session

Tags: vpn, internet-connection

I have a VPN in my office through which I connect to the Internet; but just for limited time (4 hours a day). Be connected longer than that and it expires till next day.
So, I wanna know how I can measure the time I'm connected (in multi-sessions) to that specific VPN in a single day. Remember that "VPN Status" only gives current session Duration.